# Print Column value in output when path does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which has below columns:

```
+-------+-----------------+
|   ID  |path             | 
+-------+-----------------+
|  123  | /mnt/mount/tmp1 |
|  456  | /mnt/mount/tmp2 |
|  789  | /mnt/mount/tmp3 |
+--------+----------------+
```

I get only the paths from the 2nd column and have a function that would check if the paths exist. If it does not exists it prints like below

```
Path tmp2 does not exist
```

How do I add the Id columns value too in the output

```
Path tmp2 does not exist for 456
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the DataFrame :

```
val schema: StructType = new StructType()
  .add("ID", IntegerType)
  .add("path", StringType)

val data = Seq(
  Row(123 ,"/mnt/mount/tmp1"),
  Row(456,"/mnt/mount/tmp2"),
  Row(798,"/mnt/mount/tmp3"))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),schema)

df.show()

+---+---------------+
| ID|           path|
+---+---------------+
|123|/mnt/mount/tmp1|
|456|/mnt/mount/tmp2|
|798|/mnt/mount/tmp3|
+---+---------------+
```

In your `forEach` or `ForeachParition` function, you can use the `get` function to get Column value.

```
df.foreach( row => {
  println(s"Path ${row.get(1)} dose not exist for ${row.get(0)}")
})
```

Result :

```
Path /mnt/mount/tmp3 dose not exist for 798
Path /mnt/mount/tmp2 dose not exist for 456
Path /mnt/mount/tmp1 dose not exist for 123
```

Of course, use your function to check if path exist..